# CSV file returns all list records despite using specific filters

Tags: csv

I wrote an endpoint that returns a csv file with records retrieved from a list. It returns all the records from the list correctly, but the problem is with the filters, e.g. I want to download only records with id = '12345'. In the address you can see that you set the id with a specific filter, but when I download such a csv file it returns all records without a filter set.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `CsvFilter` class does here:
`... filterData.toQuery()`  - presumably it returns a `ListQuery`

but anyway in this method you pass in that `ListQuery` then don't use it - you are shadowing that variable by creating a new variable by the same name in the second line of the method:

```
    fun getCsv(query: ListQuery): String {
        val maxPageSize = 100000
        val query = ListQuery()
        val file: Paged<List<ListDetails>> = repository.find(query)
        if (file.pagination.pageSize > maxPageSize) {
            throw LimitExceededException(maxPageSize)
        }
        val fileCsvs: List<FileCsv> = file.data.map { FileCsv.of(it) }
        return csvGenerator.generate(fileCsvs)
    }
```